# WordPress Create Taxonomy (Create different category page)

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need to create a completely different (category) taxonomy page in WordPress called "Studio".
I found this code to put in function.php.
When I create (adding) a new taxonomy (category) for example [Studio 1] and I click on the link --> mydomainname.com/studio/studio-1 it gives me --> "Oops! That page can’t be found."
How to add a new taxonomy? and get it to visualize under the post with tags list ?

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
function register_custom_taxonomies()
{
    register_taxonomy( 'Studio', 'post', array(
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Studio",
    "singular_label" => "Studio",
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Studio', 'with_front' => false ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false
    ));
}
```

Comment: This code looks right, but for it to be fully registered, you need to go to Settings > Permalinks. You shouldn't have to click save, but just visiting the permalinks page will force WP to update it's index. Then you shouldn't get the 404 on the taxonomy page.

Comment: Working !!! Thank you! is there any way to display it in the same "space" along with the categories and tags?

Comment: Do you mean in the admin? Under Posts > submenus? It's because 'label' or 'singular_label' aren't arguments. Remove those and use `'labels' => array()` here's what goes in the array: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy_labels/

Comment: I mean under the post. Under the post, with tags/categories.

Comment: Oh, you need to add it to your template if you want it to show on the front end.

Comment: I use this code in single.php
The link works, but it appears on the left side of the post in the head.
Is there any way to make it appears UNDER the post near Tags or inside tags?

`<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'Studiol' ); 
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'Studio' );
                        if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                        continue;
                    echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                    } 
                ?> `

Comment: That code doesn't help at all - since I don't know what the rest of the template looks like. You would have to move that to wherever the tags are outputting.